# search for names which have an accent

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am trying to find a way to list only the names that have an accent.

I am using the following example taken from this question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94887/what-is-the-impact-of-lc-ctype-on-a-postgresql-database

```
select firstname from (values ('bernard'), ('bérénice'), ('béatrice'), ('boris')) 
 AS l(firstname)
order by firstname collate "C";
```

Current output is

```
firstname
-------
bernard
boris
béatrice
bérénice
```

Expected output is

```
firstname
-------
béatrice
bérénice
```

Any ida what I should put in the where statement?

Comment: add a where clause to only filter names with accents

Comment: what is the filter in the where statement? Thats my question

Comment: With the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) extension: `where firstname <> unaccent(firstname)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible this will yield more than you ask for, but if you want to find all records that contain Unicode characters, you can use a regular expression for "not ASCII":

```
select firstname
from (values ('bernard'), ('bérénice'), ('béatrice'), ('boris')) 
 AS l(firstname)
where
  firstname ~ '[^[:ascii:]]'
```

Again, this will include more than just accents, but depending on your use case it might meet the need.

Comment: This is better than the rest since I am required to create an extension and my role is SQL developer not admin which wont allow me to adjust or add any db extensions! This was spot on exactly what I wanted since im only looking at a list of name and it spotted them all for me!#

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an extension first:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Then you can check with this query:

```
SELECT l.firstname 
FROM (VALUES ('bernard'), ('bérénice'), ('béatrice'), ('boris')) AS l(firstname)
WHERE l.firstname <> unaccent(l.firstname);
```